# Flipping a fraction within an Inequality?

Tags: inequality

Is it possible to flip a faction within an inequality? Such that:

$$\frac13 < x < \frac23$$

becomes,

$$3 > \frac1x > \frac32$$

Answer (score 6):

This is possible in your case because all parts are guaranteed to be $>0$. In general:

> Given a strictly monotone decreasing function $f : A\to\mathbb R$ where $A\subset \mathbb R$ is an interval and an inequality
>   $$a<b$$
>   where both $a,b\in A$ the inequality implies
>   $$f(a) > f(b)$$

In your case, $A = (0,\infty)$ and $f(x) = \frac1x$. For a non-strict version ($a\le b$) the function $f$ can be monotone (not necessarily strictly monotone).

Using $A = (-\infty, 0)$ and $f(x) = \frac1x$ also works, so
$$-\infty < a<x<b<0 \Leftrightarrow \underbrace0_{="\frac1{-\infty}"} > \frac1a > \frac1x > \frac1b > \underbrace{-\infty}_{="\frac10"}$$
and
$$0<a<x<b<\infty \Leftrightarrow \underbrace{\infty}_{="\frac10"} > \frac1a > \frac1x > \frac1b > \underbrace0_{= "\frac1\infty"}$$

But we *must* have that $a,b,x$ have the same sign.
Note that you can see that $\frac10$ cannot be defined here. In the first equation, it becomes a $-\infty$ while in the second it becomes a $+\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In general, we have
$$0\lt a\lt x\lt b\lt \infty\iff \infty\gt\frac 1a\gt \frac 1x\gt \frac 1b\gt 0.$$

Comment: Actually, adding a $\infty$ to the other side makes clear why the $0$ switches sides.

Comment: @AlexR: Im sorry for late reply! I agree with you. Thank you for pointing it out:)